# What exactly is resistance?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

I am trying to teach myself about electricity and magnetism and I have a few questions about [resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity). How does resistance of say a long wire compare to that of a a short wire? what about thick and thin? .

Comment: Hi Jtiowa, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! We expect askers to do a certain amount of basic research before posting a question here, and if you'd checked on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity), you would have found the answers you're looking for. If there's something you don't understand about that explanation, _then_ you could ask a question about it here.

Comment: @DavidZ Yeah I don't know why I even bothered writing an answer just now.  I should have made a similar comment.

Answer (score 3):

The resistance $R$ of a conductor with uniform cross-section of cross-sectional area $A$, length $\ell$, and resistivity $\rho$ is given by
\begin{align}
  R = \rho\frac{\ell}{A}.
\end{align}
The resistivity is an intrinsic measure of the resistance of the material as opposed to the resistance which depends on its size and shape.

Notice that for a fixed resistivity, the resistance of the conductor increases linearly with length and decreases like one over the cross-sectional area.  Therefore, longer wires tend to have more resistance, while thicker wires tend to have less resistance.

This makes some intuitive sense.  If you think mnemonically of a resistor like a pipe through which electrons flow, then the thicker the pipe, the easier it is for the electrons to flow.  This is a bit of a strained analogy though, because it's more like a pipe with a bunch of obstructions (atoms) in it that the electrons can collide with (which is what causes the resistance in the first place).  Given this extra input in the analogy, we can also roughly intuitively understand why resistance increases with length; the longer the pipe, the more obstructions the electrons encounter along their journey.

See, for example, this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistors_or_conductors_with_uniform_cross-section) page.